# Can I include structured data type to display tax due dates?

Tags: rich-snippets, structured-data

I tried to add structured data in my site in order to display due dates of tax deadline in search engine results page. But I don't know which data type to select.

Can I include structured data to display tax due dates?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Dated Money Specification](https://schema.org/DatedMoneySpecification) would be perfect for this use case.   You could use the endDate as the tax due date.